# Trying to capture multiple groups in regex while skipping others

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to create a single regex expression which will have the following result on two different example texts:

Example 1

- Example text 1: "App Name: Person Name"
- Captured group 1: "App Name"
- Captured group 2: "Person Name"

Example 2

- Example text 2: "App Name (1 factor): Person Name"
- Captured group 1: "App Name"
- Captured group 2: "Person Name"

The regex expression I have come up with is: `(.*)(\s\(.*\))?:\s(.*)`
But it doesn't seem to be capturing correctly and I can't see why.

I am trying this in Java on Android (and I am using a double slash to escape in the string)

Comment: `(\s\(.*\))?` is group 2 regardless if it will match something or not (`?` lets it be optional). So your matches are in group 1 and group 3. You can make `(\s\(.*\))?` non-capturing group via `(?:\s\(.*\))?`so it wouldn't be part of group indexing. Also consider making `.*` non-greedy (reluctant) by adding `.*?` in it. otherwise `.*` will try to match maximal possible match.

Comment: That seemed to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(.*?)(?:\s*\([^()]*\))?:\s*(.*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EWe5X5/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\s*\([^()]*\))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\([^()]*\)` - a `(`, zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)`
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Capturing group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is something like:

```
([A-Za-z0-9\s]*)(\s\(.*\))?:\s(.*)
```

The `(.*)` in the first group you have is capturing every character greedily. You have to specify what kind of characters can come before the `(`. I used regex101.com to test, and it seems to work for your provided cases.

Comment: Your response does work with my specific examples, although Pshemo's comment seems to provide a more general solution which will work in edge cases like if there are other characters or symbols contained in the first group.

Comment: `\w` covers `A-Za-z0-9`. Consider replacing it simply with `\w`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a non capture of `:` as so:

**Pattern**

```
([^:\n]+)\s*:\s*([^:\n]+)
```

See the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/u5rlYT/1).